# 2 different patterns when solving seemingly same equation (Completing the square)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on my math skills and I encountered this problem that puzzles me. Let me give you an example of two equations and its workings:

$4x^2 - 36x + 81$

$4\cdot (x^2 - 9x) +81$

** $4\cdot(x^2 - 9/2x + 81/4) + 81 - 4\cdot 81/4$ **

$4\cdot(x - 9/2)^2 + 81 -81$

$4\cdot(x - 9/2)^2 + 0$

and the other one which is very similar:

$2x^2 + 3x - 2$

$2\cdot(x^2 + 3/2x) - 2$

** $2\cdot (x^2 + 3/2x + 9/16) - 2 - 2\cdot 9/16$ **

$2\cdot(x + 3/4)^2 - 2 - 9/8$

$2\cdot(x + 3/4)^2 - 25/8$

I marked the two lines that are confusing me and where I keep making the same mistake. Why in the first example I square numerator and denominator but in the second example I also square numerator but then multiply the denominator by 2 and then square it ? What gives ? What I'm missing ?

Comment: The "9/2" in the first example is wrong.

Comment: Well ... I check my solution with MIT grad and it was OK.

Comment: To be exact, only the third line is wrong.

Comment: So you're saying that it should've been multiplied by 2 and squared in the third line too ???

Comment: The "9x" remains a "9x", you completed the square correct. in the next line we get "9/2"

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
(x - 9/2)^2 = x^2 - (9/2)x - (9/2)x + 81/4 &= x^2 - 9x + 81/4  \\
    &\neq x^2 - (9/2)x + 81/4  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So going from line 3 to line 4 in your first display is unjustifiable.

Given $x^2 - ax$, replace with 
$$  \rlap{\overbrace{\phantom{x^2 - (a/2)x - (a/2)x +(a/2)^2}}^{\text{binomial}}}x^2 - \underbrace{(a/2) x - (a/2) x}_{-a x} + \underbrace{(a/2)^2 - (a/2)^2}_{0} = (x-(a/2))^2 - (a/2)^2  \text{.}  $$

Comment: I'm not saying your suggested solution is wrong I just don't see how your solution is answering my question.

Comment: @MarkyMark : You are missing that there is an error in your first computation.  It is wrong.  My expression with braces shows *why* splitting the linear term in half and then adding and subtracting its square is the correct action.